# Is there any way to use map only for European region?

Tags: powerbi

I have a measures to show as bubbles in map view but while using map view am getting all locations but i need to highlight only European region only.

I have tried and i am getting like as attached image. could you please some one help to get data in European only.

Comment: _" i am getting like as attached image"_ What image?

Comment: am unable to attach image